# Yii Filter AR model based on relational table ids

Tags: php, sql, mysql, yii2

I have a database with 2 tables, one called 'Property' and the other called 'Property_Features'. They have a relation because they share the 'PropertyID' column. Property can have many Property_Features. I also have an array of Property_Feature ids. Using yii2 I want to retrieve properties which include all the desired ids in their Property_Features, destinguished by column 'FeatureID'. Why my query in yii2 doesn't work as intended? It retrieves properties even if they have only one feature id from the desired ids. The query is as follows:

```
$subquery = (new Query())
                    ->select(['COUNT(*)','PropertyID'])
                    ->from('Property_Features')
                    ->where(['in', 'FeatureID', $attributes])
                    ->groupBy('PropertyID')
                    ->having('COUNT(*) = ' . count($attributes))
                    ->limit(12)
                    ->all();
```

Which translates to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `PropertyID` FROM `Property_Features` WHERE `FeatureID` IN (157, 159) GROUP BY `PropertyID` HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 LIMIT 12
```

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FeatureID) = 2`?

Comment: @jarlh I tried but still didn't work.

Comment: The query is correct. It can't get `HAVING COUNT(*)=?` less or greater than specified. The problem is not here.